# Process 5 million key-value data in python.Will NoSql solve?

Tags: python, nosql

I would like to get the suggestion on using No-SQL datastore for my particular requirements.

**Let me explain:**
         I have to process the five csv files. Each csv contains 5 million rows and also The common id field is presented in each csv.So, I need to merge all csv by iterating 5 million rows.So, I go with python dictionary to merge all files based on the common id field.But here the bottleneck is you can't store the 5 million keys in memory(< 1gig) with python-dictionary.
So, I decided to use No-Sql.I think It might be helpful to process the 5 million key value storage.Still I didn't have clear thoughts on this.

Anyway we can't reduce the iteration since we have the five csvs each has to be iterated for updating the values.

Is it there an simple steps to go with that?
  If this is the way Could you give me the No-Sql datastore to process the key-value pair?

**Note:** We have the values as list type also.

Comment: Hint: "lakh" is a pretty regional term and not universally understood. "5 Million" or "5000000" would probably be understood more widely.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - I had to Google it - I didn't know if it was some specific data format/acronym

Comment: sorry about that..edited

Comment: @JonClements: it seems to be very commonly used in Indian English. The only reason I know about it is because I stumbled over it quite frequently on the old Java forums.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, It's quite common term in india.

Comment: 5M not so big value for relational DB. Even if you use all 5M rows in product base. NOSQL DB easy for use when you coudn't create schema for yor DB. About you task. Use temp table. Load data in temp tables, then merge it. Even on MySQL it will be fast.

Comment: But if schema in csv file not stable... Use mongoDB and prepare server with maxed memory. Mongo fast when all DBs are in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV is already sorted by id you can use the [merge-join algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join). It allows you to iterate over the single lines, so you don't have to keep everything in memory.

Extending the algorithm to multiple tables/CSV files will be a greater challenge, though. (But probably faster than learning something new like Hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to merge about 500,000 items from 5 input files. If you do this on one machine it might take long time to process 1g of data. So I suggest to check the possibility of using Hadoop. [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is a batch processing tool. Usually Hadoop programs are written in Java, but you can write it in [Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) as well.

I recommend to check feasibility of using Hadoop to process your data in a cluster. You may use HBase (Column datastore) to store your data. It's an idea, check whether its applicable to your problem.

If this does not help, give some more details about the problem your are trying to solve. Technically you can use any language or datastore to solve this problem. But you need to find which one solves the best (in terms of time or resources) and your willingness to use/learn a new tool/db.

Excellent tutorial to get started: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a one-time process, you might want to just setup an EC2 node with more than 1G of memory and run the python scripts there. 5 million items isn't that much, and a Python dictionary should be fairly capable of handling it. I don't think you need Hadoop in this case.

You could also try to optimize your scripts by reordering the items in several runs, than running over the 5 files synchronized using iterators so that you don't have to keep everything in memory at the same time.